# Solve a linear differential equation and find the limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Solve $ \dfrac{dy}{dt} - 6y = 3e^{2t}$, with $y(0) = A$.

So for the solution I get

$y= \dfrac{-3}{4}e^{2t} + \dfrac{A+ \dfrac{3}{4}}{e^{-6t}} $

As $t \rightarrow \infty$, for what values of $A$ does $y \rightarrow 0$?

Here is my work:

$0= \dfrac{-3}{4}e^{2t} + \dfrac{A+ \dfrac{3}{4}}{e^{-6t}} $

Rearrange I get:

$A= \dfrac{3}{4}e^{-4t} - \dfrac{3}{4} $

and as $t \rightarrow \infty$, $A = \dfrac{-3}{4}$

But this is not the correct answer, can anyone point out to me where I did wrong?

Comment: There's *no* right answer: all terms in your solution blow up as $t\to\infty$ & you cannot get them to cancel each other out either.  Typo in problem statement maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, $y(t) = (A+3/4)e^{6t}-\frac 34 e^{2t}$. However, whatever the initial condition, the absolute values of the solution goes to infinity.

Indeed, if $A\ne-0.75$, then the dominating term in the solution is $e^{6t}$. which goes to infinity. If $A=-0.75$, then $y(t)=-0.75e^{2t}$ and goes to $-\infty$, too.

THe problem with your reasoning that you took $y(t) = (A+3/4)e^{6t}-\frac 34 e^{2t}$ and passed to the limit on the left side (replaced $y$ with zero), but didn't do the same on the right side. This allowed to multiply by an appropriate exponent and yielded erroneous results.